# C++ trivial struct types for overload resolution

Tags: c++

As an example - assume I have function accepting three integer arguments and want to create a date - e.g. something like:

```
std::chrono<something> make_date(int year, int month, int day) {
   ...
}
```

this api is dangerous because it is simple to mix the order of the arguments - i.e. a Norwegian might be tempted to call it like `make_date(25, 12, 2021)` to get christmas day. I have seen patterns where people make (zero overhead?) struct types like

```
struct Day ...
struct Month ...
struct Year ...

std::chrono<something> make_date(Year y, Month m, Day d) {

}

auto christmas_day = make_date(Year{2021}, Month{12}, Day{25});
```

but the details of the pattern elude me.

**Update:** Since my real use case is actually not about dates at all I will make an alternative example which is much closer to the real thing. I have a immutable container with a `global_size` but many of the elements in the container are empty - so the number of nonempty elements corresponding the `active_size`is much smaller than the global size. The elements in the container are quite large - so only the active are stored:

```
template <typename T>
class container {

const T& get(std::size_t global_index) const {
    auto active_index = this->index_map.at(global_index);
    return this->storage[active_index];
}


private:
    std::vector<T> storage;                 
    std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> index_map;
}
```

Now the point is that I want to create an overload which takes an index in the space `[0, active_size>` and returns directly from the storage:

```
const T& get(std::size_t active_index) const {
    return this->storage[active_index];
}
```

but since the `get(std::size_t) const` slot is already taken by
the method which takes an index in the space `[0, global_size>` that is not a direct option. That was why I thought I could make simple struct like

```
struct ActiveIndex ...
struct GlobalIndex ...
```

essentially glorified `std::size_t`- but still enough to provide basis for overload resolution.

**Update 2:** OK - turns out this was less of magic than I thought;

```
struct Day {
    int value;
};
```

and accessing the internal int value as `.value` was all there was to it.

Comment: What about using a structure with year, month and day?

Comment: Sure that is possible - I used the date example only to illustrate the desire/need to differentiate between different arguments of the same type. My real case is not about dates.

Comment: @user422005 what is the real case?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Please add a sentence ending in a question mark.

Comment: Also consider having two functions with different names. `getByActiveIndex(42)` could be a bit mor readable than `get(42, ActiveIndex{})`. I know it doesn't look very C++-ey, but why not try something radically new once in a while? It might catch on...

Comment: Regarding Update 2 - for the above usage, `value` member in `Day` should be `const`

Comment: @user107511 if you don't want to modify, you can simply accept `const Day`